# Store data in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form to fill which has several input fileds and 20 checkbox My question is how to organize the records of the selected checkbox in mysql and what is the best way to search for them with php. Can you give me an example?

Comment: more Details, please. How many of these checkboxes get selected usually? What do you need them for? Are they related with the other input fields in any way? How many records will get stored in your table?

Comment: Could you give more details?  Are the checkboxes dynamic? That is, the form itself coming off a database?

Comment: Can _you_ give _us_ an example of the code you are trying to do?

Comment: It'd be too time consuming for me at the moment, but I can give you a tip. Common way to store lots of checkboxes/yes-no options etc. is to serialize them into one text string and put in a char(n) field.

Comment: Maybe you want to look at a simple online survey software and see what they do. Usually there should be checkbox questions.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL is a relational database, so why store all these strings?

What about something like this:

Assume your checkboxes are placed horizontally. So it´s rather intuitive to treat them like this in the database. Let´s say your forms is like:

1. What kind of food do you like (multiple answers possible) ?

   O Pizza   O Pasta   O Sushi  O Salad

Assume someone likes everything but Sushi.Someone else might only like Sushi

So your results table in the database could look like:

```
id(PK)  user        question     col      answer
1       someone     1             1         1
2       someone     1             2         1
3       someone     1             3         0
4       someone     1             4         1
5       someoneelse 1             3         1
```

Where answer is some flag that is 1 when the box is checked and is 0 if not.

I am just guessing what you mean like everyone does, so maybe I can give a better answer, if you´d ask a little more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single BIGINT field, letting each bit represent one of the property's characterizations.

Let's say you define the properties as follows

```
 1 = furnished (000001b)
 2 = with garage (000010b)
 4 = new construction (000100b)
 8 = ... (001000b)
16 = ..... (010000b)
```

So if the field's first bit is 1, that means the property is furnished, if the 3rd bit is 1, then it's a new construction, and so on.

You use the bitwise operators to check for each characterization, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM property WHERE characterization & 2
```

will return the properties with garage. Similarly

```
SELECT * FROM property WHERE characterization & 5
```

will return properties that are new constructions and are also furnished (eh.. well, you get the idea :-) ).

Keep in mind that BIGINT is 64bits, so you can't have more than 64 different characterizations in the same field.

Comment: This violates 1st NF - which you should never do without a good reason

Comment: True enough. I agree this solution may be less than ideal for this particular problem.

Answer (score -1):

If they are not in different groups but many options then you could store them in a string like that |option1:yes|option2:no|.... and you could easily query for different options like WHERE option LIKE '%|option1:yes|%', or something like that.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of search ?

Comment: What do you wan to search for? As I said if you are looking for certain option just add WHERE option LIKE '%|option1:yes|%' to your query, where option is the table column and option1 is the one you are looking for.

Comment: very inefficient method. getting values with LIKE '%...%' is very very slow and such scenario should be avoided and only used in special cases.